# Problem with Pymongo : Want to add new fields to existing db with different values but all entries turn out to be the same

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database of reviews and want to create a new field in my database that indicates whether a review contains words relating to "pool".

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.Hotels_Copenhagen
collection = db.get_collection("hotel_review_table")

data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))

def common_member(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    if a_set & b_set:
        return True
    else:
        return False

pool_set = {"pool","swim","swimming"}


for single_review in data.review_text:
    make_it_lowercase = str(single_review).lower()
    tokenize_it = re.split("\s|\.|,", make_it_lowercase)
    pool_mentioned = common_member(tokenize_it, pool_set)
    db.hotel_review_table.update_one({}, {"$set":{"pool_mentioned": pool_mentioned}})
```

In python I already counted the amount of reviews containing words related to "pool" and it turns out that 1k/ 50k of my reviews talk about pools.

I solved my previously posted problem of getting the same entry everywhere by moving the db.hotel_review_table.update_one line into the loop.

Thus the main problem is solved. However, it takes quite some time to update the database like this. Is there any other way to make it faster ?

Comment: Please add the remaining code between the update call and how you're relating that back to the set. From what I can see, it appears that you're creating a single boolean value, and then setting the entire collection to that individual boolean. I don't see you typing that boolean back to a single review.

Comment: thanks @Jacobm001 ,  you got my mistake ! thanks a lot. I solved it now by moving the line into the loop. However -as stated in the updated question - it takes a long time to update the database this way. Do you know any way to make it faster ? 

Thanks again a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gone to a lot of trouble to implement a feature that is available straight out of the box in MongoDB . You need to use [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/).

Create a text index (in MongoDB shell):

```
db.hotel_review_table.createIndex( { "single_review": "text" } )
```

Then your code distils down to:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['Hotels_Copenhagen']

for keyword in ['pool', 'swim', 'swimming']:
    db.hotel_review_table.update_many({'single_review': keyword}, {'$set': {'pool_mentioned': True}})
```

Note this doesn't set the value to false in the case that it isn't mentioned; if this is really needed, you can write another update to set any values that aren't true to false.

Comment: hey @Belly Buster ,

that looks really fantastic and I will try it out to see how much faster my code runs like this. The only "problem" I have is that I don't directly see how MongoDB tokenizes (e.g is everything put to small etc. ). But I'll certainly try it out. 

Great help! Thank you very much !